# "The client needs to convert the JSON into HTML" meaning

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, encoding, single-page-application

In this article [Escaping the SPA rabbit hole with modern Rails](https://medium.com/@jmanrubia/escaping-the-spa-rabbit-hole-with-turbolinks-903f942bf52c)
it says that

> “The client needs to convert the JSON into HTML before rendering
>   anything”.

What exactly does that mean?

Is the JSON payload comprised of data values, for example “price : 100” with which you update a HTML control that already exists on the client i.e a Drop down list?

,or,

does the JSON payload contain snippets of UI encoded somehow in JSON, for example an encoded Drop down list, together with the data values to populate it with, which the client will render both? in that case also altering/adding new controls to the UI (consisting of HTML) of the client?

Comment: The first one. The client side application is responsible for taking the raw data from the API (usually in JSON format) and via a templating system rendering the HTML on the screen

Comment: what about http://www.json2html.com/

Comment: That's exactly what json2html does. Takes JSON data and applies a template to turn it into HTML. In this case the templates are defined in JSON too, but the HTML is still generated client side if used in a SPA.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is data format it will contain data that needs to be transformed into view elements in case of browser HTML is needed before end user will see anything but such JSON data can be also used in other applications that don't need HTML and are using different means to visualize that data.